# Couchbase counter giving NOT_EXISTS error

Tags: scala, rx-java, couchbase, couchbase-java-api

Following is the code to update counter.

```
kvList contains List[(key, value to add)]

def counter(kvList: List[(String, Long)]) = {
  try {`enter code here`
   if (kvList!=null && kvList.nonEmpty) {
    Observable.from(kvList).flatMap(kv => {
     val bucketObservableAsync =
     rx.lang.scala.JavaConversions.toScalaObservable(
         bucket.async().counter(kv._1, kv._2, kv._2, ttl)
     )

    def errorOccurred(t: Throwable): Unit = {
      log.error("ReportingService observable error occurred", t)
    }

    bucketObservableAsync.doOnError(errorOccurred)
    bucketObservableAsync
    }).last.toBlocking.single
    } else {
      log.info("ReportingService no keys to update")
    }
  } catch {
    case e: Throwable =>
    log.error("ReportingService error occurred ", e)
  }
}
```

I'm using couchbase java-client-2.1.3 and I could see 2 issues over here:

```
The errorOccurred is not getting called
```

Instead of (1) I'm getting the following exception sometimes:

```
ReportingService error occurred
com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseException: NOT_EXISTS
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncBucket$26.call(CouchbaseAsyncBucket.java:950)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncBucket$26.call(CouchbaseAsyncBucket.java:932)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
    at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:65)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
    at rx.subjects.AsyncSubject.onCompleted(AsyncSubject.java:105)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler$1.call(AbstractGenericHandler.java:199)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: What further info is required?

Comment: Expert of this topic (whose I'm not myself) will tell you, if further info is needed.